# Nginx rewrite rules for Angularjs to remove # hash in url in dynamic routes

Tags: angularjs, nginx, routes, config, html5mode

I have done the following:

**AngularJS app**

In app.js:

`$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`

In index.html:

`<base href="/">`

**nginx config**

`location / {
                try_files $uri /index.html;
        }`

After deployment, things are working fine (# hash sign is removed) with the static pages. I can go directly to `http://fakeurl/about` or `http://fakeurl/download` pages; if I refresh the browser, the pages still load.

However, when I go directly to a dynamic page:

`http://fakeurl/cars/:car_id`

Then nginx will serve 404.

If I use the # path, then it redirects to the path without the # sign and displays the page; but when I refresh the page again, it shows 404. (This only happens with dynamic routes)

`http://fakeurl/#/cars/:car_id`

`http://fakeurl/#/shops/:shop_id`

What rewrite rules do I need to write in the nginx blocks to serve my dynamic routes? Thanks!

Comment: You just need to load index.html, which you are doing, can you check what file is it trying to access, causing 404(check in error or access log)?

Answer (score 0):

I burnt all my midnight oil last night and I found a solution here. If you have a better one, please post here so I can learn

https://gist.github.com/mreigen/4dc8effec8186315c3aac4ce6da46c9a

Comment: proxy_pass is the key

Comment: I have exactly the same case i think.. but i did not quite get it which lines of the referenced github page is relevant for us?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this regex pattern `^(.*)\/#`and rewrite it with `$1`.